# How to make a DXGrid of DevExpress for SilverLight readonly?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devexpress

How to make a DXGrid of DevExpress for SilverLight readonly? I want to make this a readonly grid such that the user cannot edit the cells when he clicks on any row.

I searched far and wide, but there is nothing like:

gridcontrol.readonly   NOT THERE

gridcontrol.isreadonly NOT THERE

gridcontrol-->behaviour-->editing  something like this NOT THERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the grid's View.AllowEditing property to false to prohibit editing.